# Multiple table header <thead> in table <table> and how to scrape data from <thead> as a table row

Tags: python, web-scraping

I'm trying to scrape data from a website but the table has two sets of data, first, 2-3 lines of data are in thead and rest in tbody. I can easily extract data only from one at a time when I try both I got some error like TypeError, AttributeError. btw I'm using python 
here is the code

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

url="https://www.worldometers.info/world-population/"
r=requests.get(url)
print(r)

html=r.text
soup=BeautifulSoup(html,'html.parser')

print(soup.title.text)
print()
print()
live_data=soup.find_all('div',id='maincounter-wrap')
print(live_data)
for i in live_data:
    print(i.text)

table_body=soup.find('thead')
table_rows=table_body.find_all('tr')
table_body_2=soup.find('tbody')
table_rows_2=soup.find_all('tr')
year_july1=[]
population=[]
yearly_change_in_perchantage=[]
yearly_change=[]
median_age=[]
fertillity_rate=[]
density=[]#density (p\km**)
urban_population_in_perchantage=[]
urban_population=[]

for tr in table_rows:


    td=tr.find_all('td')
    year_july1.append(td[0].text)
    population.append(td[1].text)
    yearly_change_in_perchantage.append(td[2].text)
    yearly_change.append(td[3].text)
    median_age.append(td[4].text)
    fertillity_rate.append(td[5].text)
    density.append(td[6].text)
    urban_population_in_perchantage.append(td[7].text)
    urban_population.append(td[8].text)

for tr in table_rows_2:


    td=tr.find_all('td')
    year_july1.append(td[0].text)
    population.append(td[1].text)
    yearly_change_in_perchantage.append(td[2].text)
    yearly_change.append(td[3].text)
    median_age.append(td[4].text)
    fertillity_rate.append(td[5].text)
    density.append(td[6].text)
    urban_population_in_perchantage.append(td[7].text)
    urban_population.append(td[8].text)

headers=['year_july1','population','yearly_change_in_perchantage','yearly_change','median_age','fertillity_rate','density','urban_population_in_perchantage','urban_population']

data_2= pd.DataFrame(list(zip(year_july1,population,yearly_change_in_perchantage,yearly_change,median_age,fertillity_rate,density,urban_population_in_perchantage,urban_population)),columns=headers)
print(data_2)
data_2.to_csv("C:\\Users\\data_2.csv")
```

Comment: Show us what you have tried so far.

Comment: welcome to SO. Take a read [hear](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) on some tips on how to ask your question. As is, your question can't and won't be answered. As 1) it's really broad, 2) you have not displayed any code as to show what you've tried or to have others reproduce your issue

Comment: sorry for that, i updated my question

Comment: Hi Please do not create duplicate questions for the same problem.
Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60948627/how-to-select-thead-then-tbody-when-scraping-data-from-web-page-using-python/60948857#60948857

Comment: sry for that ,deleted previous one

Comment: @R_J_ did you try running the below code.? and check the data.csv?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try the below code it generates the required data. Do let me know if you need any clarification:-

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
url = 'https://www.worldometers.info/world-population/'
html = requests.get(url).content
df_list = pd.read_html(html, header=0)
df = df_list[0]
    #print(df)
df.to_csv("data.csv", index=False)
```

gives me below output

```
print(df)
    Year (July 1)  Population  ... Urban Pop %  Urban Population
0            2020  7794798739  ...      56.2 %        4378993944
1            2019  7713468100  ...      55.7 %        4299438618
2            2018  7631091040  ...      55.3 %        4219817318
3            2017  7547858925  ...      54.9 %        4140188594
4            2016  7464022049  ...      54.4 %        4060652683
5            2015  7379797139  ...      54.0 %        3981497663
6            2010  6956823603  ...      51.7 %        3594868146
7            2005  6541907027  ...      49.2 %        3215905863
8            2000  6143493823  ...      46.7 %        2868307513
9            1995  5744212979  ...      44.8 %        2575505235
10           1990  5327231061  ...      43.0 %        2290228096
11           1985  4870921740  ...      41.2 %        2007939063
12           1980  4458003514  ...      39.3 %        1754201029
13           1975  4079480606  ...      37.7 %        1538624994
14           1970  3700437046  ...      36.6 %        1354215496
15           1965  3339583597  ...        N.A.              N.A.
16           1960  3034949748  ...      33.7 %        1023845517
17           1955  2773019936  ...        N.A.              N.A.

[18 rows x 9 columns]
```

Comment: World Population (2020 and historical) on same site

Comment: can you try now

Comment: thnx for that......but can u tell me whts the diff. between my code using bs4 and urs without bs4.....

Comment: Sure, the read_html method is very simple actually searches for table recursively and returns a list of data frames. Then you index it for the required df. You can actually go through the documentation https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.read_html.html